# Trouble prompting the user for an input file, and returning with a series of information [Perl]

Tags: regex, perl, input, sum, output

I am trying to create a simple program that does these five things

1. Prompts the user for an input file.
2. Prompts the user file does not exist if a user specifies an unknown document (Case 1)
3. The file is not a regular file (Case 2)
4. There is an issue with opening the file that the user has submitted (Case 3)
5. The file specified has (1) data that is not a valid number, or (2) more than one number on the line. (Case 4)
6. The file exists and can be opened with no errors.  The file must contain a single number (any decimal or neg/pos integer), and calculate the sum, number of numbers in the file, and the mean/average (Case 5).

I have labeled the cases on the code I am providing.  Every time I run this, I do not get errors, but the same response in return.  I am trying this to improve my file scanning skills.  If anyone has any knowledge on this topic I would be more than grateful.  Thanks in advance.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

print ("Enter a file name: "); 

my $infile = <STDIN>; #Prompts the user for input
chomp ($infile); #Chomps the $infile Variable.

#****CASE ONE****
if (-e $infile) { 

        print ("File '$infile' does not exist.\n");
            exit;
}

#****CASE TWO****
elsif (-f $infile) { 

        print ("Not a regular file or directory.\n");
            exit;
}

#****CASE THREE****
open ( my $input, '<', $infile ) or die $!;
print ("Can not open input file '$infile': Permission denied. ");

#****CASE FOUR****

#for (my $inf = 1; ; ++$_)
my $inf = 9**9**9;

if (-e $infile =~ /^[a-zA-Z]+$/) { 

    } else {
        print ("File '$infile' containts invalid data.\n");
            exit;
}

#****Case Five****
my $Int_Pos = 0;
my $Int_Neg = 0;
my $Int_Dec = 0;

open(FHIN, '<', $infile); #Opens the file prompted by user. 
my @lines = <FHIN>; #Variable storing the number of lines in the file.
chomp( @lines ); 
close(FHIN); #File handle is closed. 

while (my $line = <$input> ) { #iterates the file line by line, making $_ as teh defaule variable. 
    $Int_Pos++ if $line >= 0;
    $Int_Neg++ if $line >= 0;
    $Int_Dec++ if $line >= 0;
    my $sum = $Int_Pos + $Int_Neg + $Int_Dec;
    my $Observations = @lines;
    my $Mean = $sum/3;

    print ("Sum: '$sum'\n");
    print ("Observations: '$Observations'\n");
    print ("Mean: '$Mean'\n");  
}
```

Comment: *"Every time I run this, I do not get errors, but the same response in return."* And which response is that? Presumably "File does not exist" for files that really do exist and "No such file or directory" for files that don't exist. Your logic is all wonky: `-e` and `-f` mean the file *does* exist, you print "Permission denied" after successfully opening files, etc.

Comment: Yes; I do get the "File doe not exist" as my return.  How would I use the -e and -f operators the other way around (if the file doesn't actually exist, it returns the correct message)?

Comment: *"The file must contain a single number ... and calculate the sum, number of numbers in the file, and the mean/average"* You want to calculate the sum and mean of *one number*?

Comment: Is this homework? The best test for all those criteria is just to `open` the file and report any errors.

Comment: Borodin - I want to calculate the mean of all of the numbers listed in the .txt file.  so if the file had the numbers: 55, 66, and 43, I would add those together and divide by the number of numbers in the file (in our case 3).  And yes it is for homework.  I can't make my professor's office hours due to schedule conflicts and this is my only real source of help.

Comment: There's a cognitive dissonance between your code and your words. i.e., the things you are saying do not match what your code is trying to do.

Comment: You shouldn't hard-code `Permission denied` as the reason for the `open` to fail. There are many reasons why it might have failed, and the error message is saved in built-in variable `$_`

Comment: What is the test `-e $infile =~ /^[a-zA-Z]+$/` supposed to do? The expression doesn't make sense, and doesn't seem to correspond to any of the steps in your narrative.

Answer (score 1):

okay, so there are multiple things wrong:

`if (-e $infile)`   should be

```
`if (not -e $infile)  `
```

`elsif (-f $infile)`  has the same issue of testing the opposite of what you want `elsif (not -f $infile)`

also, this print will happen when the file DOES open:`

```
open ( my $input, '<', $infile ) or die $!;
print ("Can not open input file '$infile': Permission denied. ");`
```

instead change it to:

```
`open ( my $input, '<', $infile ) or die("Can not open input file '$infile': $!");`
```

this line is nonsensical `if (-e $infile =~ /^[a-zA-Z]+$/)`
    im guessing in case 4 you will want something along the lines of
    
    `foreach $line (<$infile >){
        $matches = () = $line =~ /^(\d+)$/;
        if($matches != 1){
            die "line does not contain a single number";
        }
        $sum += $1;
    }`

this is a hasty, approximate code that doesn't use strict (you should use strict!) which should help you figure out the rest

Answer (score -1):

You are using the $infile as your input

```
#****CASE THREE****
open ( my $input, '<', $infile ) or die $!;
```

I would do something like this ...

```
open ( my $input, '<', "somefile.txt" ) or die $!;
```

Comment: deal with each error,  I just gave you a starting off point for your home work

Comment: That part of the OP's code is actually fine. They want to open the file specified by the user, not a hard-coded filename.